# Use Jenkins REST API to rebuild a build

Tags: jenkins

I have a build in Jenkins which has failed for a temporary reason. I'd like to just re-build it. On the website I just click "rebuild" (from the rebuild plug-in), and if it is a parameterized job, I get asked if I want to keep the parameters. Importantly, the new job contains a "rebuild" link back to the original job enabling back-tracing.

How can I effect this "rebuild" from the REST API. I have code that will get a completed job, extract the parameters, and invoke a new job with those same parameters - so I've got most of the way there.

But I don't know how to establish the rebuild link so I can trace what job is a rebuild of what other job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rebuild plugin did not implement a REST API as of version 1.25. (Update: as of version 1.34, this is apparently supported, see hpjules' answer -- the below text refers to version 1.25).

If your job has no parameters, then just GETing the `<buildUrl>/rebuild` URL should trigger a rebuild, though.

If your job *does* have parameters, then some more scripting will be needed to mimick what you do manually in those two steps.

Comment: Thanks! I'd come to this conclusion myself, but as I'm still learning how to use Jenkins, I was hoping it was an oversight on my part.

Comment: My jenkins has auth required, and I couldn't get `rebuild` to work using BASIC auth. Do you need to send cookie auth or something?

Answer (score 2):

For those who ran exactly to the same question, this is now possible since 1.34 of the [rebuilder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/rebuild/) plugin. For example:

```
https://jenkins.io/project/job/testing/1
```

Can be rebuilt via API with

```
https://jenkins.io/project/job/testing/1/rebuild?autorebuild=true
```

The feature wasn't documented properly I'm afraid and was just able to find out by browsing the [commits](https://github.com/jenkinsci/rebuild-plugin/commit/02c3f3f320199a2d9f3435fa54921f1484af9c3d).